# iPhone : Posting an image to facebook's wall with comment message using oAuth support

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Posting an image to facebook's wall with comment message using oAuth support from the latest sdk provided by facebook.
Please provide useful links.

Comment: See [How To Use Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app) by Ray Wenderlich.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here to integrate the latest Facebook SDK and get a valid session: [Facebook SDK for iOS Getting Started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

There is a sample app included with the SDK to get you started as well.

Then in your code, do something like this, where "session" is declared

```
Facebook * session;

- (void) sendFacebookMessage:(NSString *) messageText withCaption:(NSString *) captionText) andImage:(UIImage *) image {
    NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [args setObject:captionText forKey:@"caption"];
    [args setObject:messageText forKey:@"message"];
    [args setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7) forKey:@"picture"];

    [session requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload" andParams:args ndHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through the documentation.